# Interpretation of stopping times

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

I know the following question is an often asked question on this website, but I still don't really catch it...

If $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ are stopping times, then how can I interpret the sum of $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ or there product? How do I know intuitively that the sum of two stopping times is still a stopping time, but the product of them is not? Could you give me an example from real life?

I know stopping time is a random variable, and I interpret it as a "time", when an event happens and in the moment when it happens I can decide that it has actually happened or not. I can decide it in the moment when it happens, so I don't need to wait or see into the future to know it has happened. Perhaps this explanation a little bit confused and not "well defined", but I hope you get what I mean...

Comment: Intuitively, you can decide whether $\tau_1+\tau_2\le t$ because it only concerns events such that $\tau_1\le t$ and $\tau_2\le t$. However, $\tau_1+\tau_2\le t$ could be achieved for instance for $\tau_1=t/2$ and $\tau_2=2t$, the latter being undecidable.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3308592/understanding-a-proof-of-sum-of-stopping-times